# c++ How to fix std::cin bug or work around it

Tags: c++, c++11, cin, getline, libc++

I'm using Apple LLVM 3.0 and apparently there is a bug with `std::getline` and `cin.getline`, which requires the user to push enter twice in order for the `std::getline` function to return control back to program. Take this sample code for example:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    using namespace std;

    string str;

    cout << "Enter some text: ";
    getline(cin, str);

    cout << "\nYou Entered: " << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Enter some text: hello world
```

I press enter once and the program is still running and waiting for input. I have to push enter again in order for the program to stop asking for input and continue execution.

I've searched for answers and this is apparently a bug in libc++, a similar bug also present in MS VC++ 6.0 (I think).

I tried a workaround by implementing my own getline function using cin.get(char) and returns when it encounters a '\n' or '\r' character. Here is the code below:

```
std::istream& getline(std::istream &in, std::string &str) {
    char ch;

    str.clear();

    while (in.get(ch) && ch != '\n' && ch != '\r') {
        str += ch;
    }

    return in;
}
```

Unfortunately I still have the same problem as the first new line character is not returned by in.get hence the program once again hangs waiting for the user to push enter for the second time. Is there any workaround or solution to this problem without resorting to good old C-style `fgets(stdin, buffer, bufsize)`.

Comment: Add `<< std::fflush`  after each output to `cout`

Comment: Have an ignore before getline (maybe)

Comment: Tried both. I still have the same problem of having to push enter twice.

Comment: It's a bug. You can report it [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In my original program I have turned off synchronization with stdio, as I try to avoid the old C way of doing things, hence the call to fflush would be useless.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's already been reported there a couple of times, that's how I discovered it's a bug, unfortunately there is no information anywhere on how to resolve this issue for Apple LLVM, the only fix available is for a similar bug in MS VC++.

Comment: Is the bug reported? bug id?

Answer (score 1):

This is the only workaround I have found so far. Here's my own version of getline:

```
std::istream& getline(std::istream &in, std::string &str) {
    char chr;
    std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = in.flags();

    str.clear();

    while ((in >> std::noskipws >> chr) && (chr != '\n') && (chr != '\r')) {
        str += chr;
    }

    in.flags(flags);
    return in;
}
```

The above function works as `std::getline` is expected to, it returns after the first enter is pushed.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this using the latest release of Xcode and Apple's LLVM, and couldn't reproduce this.
(i.e, I only had to hit *return* once)

```
$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

I built it like this:

```
$ clang++ -stdlib=libc++ so.cpp
```